# Building project in maven : Want to avoid few modules

Tags: maven, build

I am trying to build a maven project and want to keep few modules deactivated. How can this be achived either command prompt or IDE (i am using IntelliJ IDEA)? Also is it a good practice?

I was wondering if it makes sense to run a Project without letting all the modules build.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable and valid to build select modules in a project as long as you understand the implications. You can try all these options from both your IDE and command line.

You have a few choices:

1) If you feel it's easy to mention the modules you want to build in a reactor every time you run the build, use the `-pl`/`--projects` reactor option. You may even need to know about the `--also-make` and `--also-make-dependents` while you're at it. Read about them [here](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/#.VGvhPcmEcWg).

like

```
mvn clean install -pl <comma separated list of projects to include in the build>
```

2) Instead of typing it out every time, if you wanted to group the projects you want to build often, configure `Profile`s (see [how](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_activation) to activate them):

```
<project>
  ...
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
  <modules>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>buildOften</id>
      <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

3) It's also good to create a separate POM to group the modules logically that you want to build often and name it accordingly. You'll then need to run the build pointing to this POM. Like:

```
mvn clean install -f pom-special.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @mystarrocks for the detail and clear explanation.
Hope I am able to do better with maven in near future.